# Removing a comma at the end of String

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an HashSet into comma seperated delimited String 
But the problem is that , i am getting an extra comma at the end of the String also as shown .
Please tell me how can i remove that extra comma at the end of the String .

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Test {

    private static Set<String> symbolsSet = new HashSet<String>();

    static {

        symbolsSet.add("Q1!GO1");
        symbolsSet.add("Q2!GO2");
        symbolsSet.add("Q3!GO3");

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] a = symbolsSet.toArray(new String[0]);
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            sb.append(a[i] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());

    }

}
```

Output :

```
Q3!GOO3,Q2!GO2,Q1!GO1,
```

Comment: BTW, `Q3!GOO3,Q2!GO2,Q1!GO1,` is not the output you should get from your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
    sb.append(a[i] + ",");
}

sb.append(a[a.length - 1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if ( i > 0 ) {
        sb.append(",");
    }
    sb.append(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways you can do this, below is a regex solution using `String#replaceAll()`

```
String s= "abc,";
s = s.replaceAll(",$", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String separator = "";
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    sb.append(separator).append(a[i]);
    separator = ",";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your given scenario `String.lastIndexOf` method is pretty useful.

```
String withComma= sb.toString();
String strWithoutLastComma = withComma.substring(0,withComma.lastIndexOf(","));
System.out.println(strWithoutLastComma);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String str = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
```

or append only if  not last element

```
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if ( i > 0 ) {
        sb.append(",");
    }
    sb.append(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] a = symbolsSet.toArray(new String[0]);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
        //append until the last with comma
        sb.append(a[i] + ",");
    }
    //append the last without comma
    sb.append(a[a.length-1]);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(i == a.length - 1) {
             sb.append(a[i]);  // Last element. Dont append comma to it
        } else {
        sb.append(a[i] + ","); // Append comma to it. Not a last element
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String[] a = symbolsSet.toArray(new String[0]);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        sb.append(a[i] + ",");
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length - 1));

}
```

OR

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String[] a = symbolsSet.toArray(new String[0]);

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        sb.append(a[i]);

        if(a != a.length - 1)
        {
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
      if(a.length-1!=i)
            sb.append(a[i] + ",");
      else
      {
            sb.append(a[i]);
            break;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(i == a.length - 1 )
    {
        sb.append(a[i]);
    } else {
        sb.append(a[i] + ",");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could grow your own `Separator` class:

```
public class SimpleSeparator<T> {
  private final String sepString;
  boolean first = true;

  public SimpleSeparator(final String sep) {
    this.sepString = sep;
  }

  public String sep() {
    // Return empty string first and then the separator on every subsequent invocation.
    if (first) {
      first = false;
      return "";
    }
    return sepString;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleSeparator sep = new SimpleSeparator(",");
    System.out.print("[");
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
      System.out.print(sep.sep()+i);
    }
    System.out.print("]");
  }

}
```

There's loads more you can do with this class with static methods that separate arrays, collections, iterators, iterables etc.